# how to deny dirrect access to folder with some exception?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `upload` folder and i want people can't dirrect access into that folder. But people can download file from that folder from a button. Is this possilbe ? If yes, how i can setting on `.htaccess` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple php script that will return certain file, example here [PHP - simple download script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295604/php-simple-download-script) and deny access to uploads folder like here [Deny access to one specific folder in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118482/deny-access-to-one-specific-folder-in-htaccess/19118529)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line in your `upload/.htaccess` file:

```
deny from all
```

This will make that the contents cannot be listed, but can still be downloaded when the user knows the filename (or - in your case - is linked to that file from a button).

If you want to keep access to the open directory for yourself, you can add the following line (in addition to the previous):

```
allow from [your ip address]
```